# Preserve Single Quote Prefix of Cell Value of excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi

Currently i am reading excel value from my sheet
But its neglecting " ' " in cell value

```
Expected output- 'Testing
Actual output  -  Testing
```

How to display the single qoute while reading from excel

```
package utils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelDataConfig {

    XSSFWorkbook wb;
    XSSFSheet sheet1;

    public ExcelDataConfig(String excelPath) throws IOException {
        File src = new File(excelPath);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        
        
    }

    public String getData(int sheetNumber, int row, int column) {
        sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);
        String data = sheet1.getRow(row).getCell(column).getStringCellValue();
        return data;

    }
}
```

My test class

```
ExcelDataConfig excel = new ExcelDataConfig(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/testData/TestData.xlsx");
System.out.println("String with double quotes=" +excel.getData(0, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will neglect single quote as single quote in xls cell is actually a shortcut to accept data as it is.
So if you are storing 'Hello Superman' then please store it as ''Hello Superman' and it will be read correctly as 'Hello Superman'

Answer (score 1):

A leading single quote character `'` is a special character in Excel, which tells it to treat it's contents verbatim. The most common use I know of is to tell it not to format numerical values by removing leading zeroes.

When you enter a value into Excel that is prefixed with `'`, note how the quote only appears in the editing field, not in the cell as it is displayed in the sheet.

Behind the scenes the `quotePrefix` value is stored separately from the value itself.
For example, setting `'Testing` will result in the *value* being just `Testing`, with `quotePrefix=true` in the OOXML.

So technical, so good, POI reports the *value* correctly, by giving you exactly what Excel shows as the value, namely just `Testing`.
To make the single quotation mark appear in POI, access the property `CellStyle.getQuotePrefixed()` and add it manually.

So in your example you could try:

```
Cell cell = sheet1.getRow(row).getCell(column);
String data = cell.getStringCellValue();
if(cell.getCellStyle().getQuotePrefixed()) {
    data = '''+data;
}
return data;
```

With this you might (depending on use-case) run into issues where sometimes you want the prefix and in other situations you don't, especially if you're not in control of the input Excel. Arguably it might be 'more correct' to escape the single quotation mark in Excel itself, by adding a second. So in Excel you would enter `''Testing`. This would ensure that both Excel and POI report the desired value of `'Testing`, without using the above code.